# 'Unauthorized token' msg during trello api webhooks request

Tags: api, trello

I took token from `https://trello.com/app-key`
I tried to call `https://api.trello.com/1/tokens/<token>/webhooks` using `Postman`

Result: `unauthorized token.`
Expected: list of webhooks created with trello

Answer (score 0):

Every request to api should be supplied with key and token.
In this case key is enough.
`https://api.trello.com/1/tokens/<token>/webhooks?key=<key>`.